# Sublime text font on Elementary

Tags: fonts

I have an issue with my sublime text 3 installation where the text is displayed with blocks rather than actual letters. Here is what I mean:

[image]

I have tried `apt-get install --reinstall sublime-text-installer` but that failed to fix it.

Can anyone offer a suggestion as to how I can fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that I was using [**googlefonts**](https://github.com/google/fonts) which I symlinked to my `~/.fonts` directory. The link was broken when I was installing some stuff.

After cloning the repo again and creating the directory directly within the `~/.fonts` folder, everything went back to normal